# pyenv installing any python version is resulting in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'

Tags: python, linux, openssl, homebrew, pyenv

As a new user on my ubuntu WSL system I am installing python versions using pyenv to manage multiple version, I'm using the standard instructions:

I installed homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Updated brew and installed pyenv using homebrew (currently the recommended process)

```
brew update
brew install pyenv
```

Install any python version using this newly installed pyenv:

```
pyenv install 3.10.13
```

And I get the following error:

```
Downloading Python-3.10.13.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.13/Python-3.10.13.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.10.13...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/adam/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 99, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using python-build 2.3.35-5-g2d850751)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20231227145009.23362
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20231227145009.23362.log

Last 10 log lines:
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/python-build.20231227145009.23362/Python-3.10.13 ./python -E -m ensurepip \
                $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Looking in links: /tmp/tmprqhmro5y
Processing /tmp/tmprqhmro5y/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /tmp/tmprqhmro5y/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip3 and pip3.10 are installed in '/home/adam/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-23.0.1 setuptools-65.5.0
```

Any thoughts on the cause?
I've tried the following with no luck:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Removing brew's openssl resolved the issue.

Credit where credit is due:
I found a solution to this error on linux mint forums shortly after posting this question:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=402803

Rather than close the question, I'll answer it for future reference:

it looks like by the following output that brew installed openssl even though I did not realize I had explicitly have brew do this- I belive when it installed the dependencies for pyenv openssl must have been one of them.

```
adam:~/project$ brew list | grep openssl
openssl@3
```

This was causing a problem and was fixed by removing openssl from the brew install:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
```

Simply removing openssl in this way resulted in a successful environment for pyenv:

```
pyenv install 3.10.13
Downloading Python-3.10.13.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.13/Python-3.10.13.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.10.13...
Installed Python-3.10.13 to /home/adam/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13
```